# Converting Base64 Image From JSON Array On Pipeline.Ai

Tags: php, json, image, base64, decode

I am using pipeline.io to send prompts from a simple PHP form and then the script receives the JSON output. This part seems to be working fine and the image it returns based upon the prompt it is fed seems to be in the field [results_preview]. But attempting to decode it fails and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Example code and JSON:

```
JASON: Array"[{\"id\":\"model_46f42d5cc07d4074bb308e304d0ffdbb\",\"name\":\"DALL\u00b7E Mini (Legacy)\",\"hex_file\":{\"name\":\"jXZHyFLLRCRjUaGWAyqH\",\"id\":\"file_7b60ade195fb4557a90596cdddcb7c4f\",\"path\":\"object_49gbh9hbkjvw3u64xohafzij6vqkzwqregbefm3x4d36lpmvjzhfqa3i0vn45ako\",\"data\":null,\"file_size\":23898},\"source_sample\":\"@pipeline_model\\nclass DallE_Mini_Model:\\n def __init__(self):\\n self.model = None\\n\\n @pipeline_function\\n def DallE_Mini_Predict(self, prompts: List[str], inference_kwargs: dict = {}) -> L\"}],\"graph_nodes\":[{\"local_id\":\"rulrTUYrMb\",\"function\":\"function_b8fb7cbf8b314d6aa48c3f66ee3b1533\",\"inputs\":[\"EEEBgZqnpW\",\"thaTHiQGzM\"],\"outputs\":[\"CIIIBPCpGH\"]}],\"outputs\":[\"CIIIBPCpGH\"]},\"data\":{\"id\":\"data_382db91cc43c40b39fcf84b0ede61c26\",\"hex_file\":{\"name\":\"_phj6z0dxywzowoyhieftic9qp71txui2cfrr6y3yod4vsz08uw\",\"id\":\"file_5f57dd7d84b943f5a40f45d2e6bbba42\",\"path\":\"data__znvh8junqbjhfn5rtskjv0sc18stt29vb8xwhoaee0s6iwzkh0ubqdvpem1ghmzv\",\"data\":null,\"file_size\":210},\"created_at\":1660001506.265047,\"modified_at\":null,\"name\":\"_phj6z0dxywzowoyhieftic9qp71txui2cfrr6y3yod4vsz08uw\",\"size\":null,\"file_type\":null,\"token_created_by\":null,\"token_modified_by\":null,\"url\":null,\"preview\":null},\"blocking\":true,\"result\":{\"name\":\"Run run_0e5a0231ea894831b708872eae89bab9 output\",\"id\":\"file_b7b1d226953a4bec98a09dd5c14fbdf7\",\"path\":\"run_0e5a0231ea894831b708872eae89bab9_output\",\"data\":null,\"file_size\":38758},\"result_preview\":[[[\"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL\/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL\/wAARCAEAAQADASIAAhEBAxEB\/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6\/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6\/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDwosBgsOCe3SlJ6YOT7U3IbC5x7+tKow2FXJI796YACUypHTkjHOKAxAywyDx06UgU437huHBBpQw4DEg9c9qBDiw4xknsM04MVG3AI60w98KBkfSkLsfmPVeAKAHBiBkjO79KcWGO5PpmmBgdoJIPXPag8g4QdKAJNxXIOPWmq5AO4Ag8Z9Kb8x+Y8lRgAUilgBuGR69aAJCwH1xnr0p\/IUEng8jrzUbKSRgAL2HTNO2HqQSfQDgUwBXI3KRx346Um8jkjg8dOlKAwXcCDjqKb5g4ByB680AKWAxjk9uelOJwASwORkY9KiY7iBgAdPTNOVW5zyV7AdKAFVtqkMOCcfShnwRyf8KYwdVBBzzyAaR3UKFXgnqx9cUAK8xQ7AOP\/rVNZQXOoXC2tpA00jD7oUnA9T7e9V7e3lvruOCFMyyMFGTgZPr7V0txd2egWoh0ySKSRwDNKeTIR\/D7L7f4UAEGiWNrKYtUcPLGcGKFt3zfUdfSiTXdMtJQ1pp1uueVbbnj8qwJNQleVigjVc5IGcNgYqKfbtVkVVP8QUH5Dnjn3H8qQjfPi2ZZpNm1Iw2EATt+f6UHxXPIwYSPlcfKV+VvbiuZIbbjk45Ix0pAGXGDgnsKLhY7FPFylyFiTO3AwmB9KW21HS7tH+0WyCQknzUXB\/Prn\/GuQOY8AEspyRg4HpS7GQqyj3\/yKYNGvqGgS29r9st38+3PJGPnUe4\/rWPGxbKkDB59K6DSdVuoZYsM4UnGCMqfzqtqunR2zpPC6lJiTsUY2EHkUxIzx8q5IPI79uakPYgk9xTSVIAPKqOtKxCjCryeDkUhgMruTGfX1pykggnp2+tNG\/G4DJHB\/wD10ZGADk55zmgCtkZA7juKFwzHPLHn0FIuFzlck8Yp0bKh+bPuR6UijTuNJ8nSor0XUbh2C+WBhsn2rKLHpj7vHGadu+T0TPQVIuAQyouQOSx4oAa23CliSD3HakJPrubHXNOeN\/lJU7AO47UzqPlHagB5UrjJwe30p0cbSONwLZ64\/hqS3h83B6nOBtrcsdNQLG5kIPJb39v85oEYbQkAD5mPTngCrS2eIwdzAY7jg1uzwIsZJVMsMFiP0p8NsJIFHypGCQwbGTgf\/q\/KgZyshBnCsTwBnaKaxBfy9xI6Z5A9q2rvTEBeRRlsgjvj6Vt+F\/hjrvik+csQtLPGTczKV\/75HU0COHk4wDnr0yOtJ5nA7AdRnJr3e1+COiwKDfazJK46iMYGfxpj\/Bnw9IzC21W4if8AvOAR+VAHhnDuSSwIw2cdKZuBkBcsY8\/MBXdeJvhvqnheN7lHju7FTgzRjp9V7VwzbSRuBC0ABwq8c56c1HJuBGeD1BI606RdqDAIGcEt60cKRluRx06c0ATabef2ffx3WCWTPH1BGf1qpI5lkdwDgnJ74oO7G7j2Irv5vDpbSlurWFXE3ylyAc8YOM9qAPP8ZIUHOau21o7Dc8Tbd2M+2Occdv5ketdMfCUwtmAj8uQOcnOT+f51ch0JntIYWdlZMnnB9OM9+lAHKiFTIYUjCfL25J56+3SnXOmyeQuyEYRclvWuoOhGKcGVRIwAJx6HvWgHQ4iuI1DbSCQM7h\/k0Aeaf6xjgBSOQScU4O8cm1Wy4+XPX\/PerusxxwXziIsNw5UjtWWGIOetAGl9smt0ilhchsYbAP8A+r8q07SWPUtMvI2XM6YkiYHnA+8MfTJ9PpWNYrbPcot1Ky25P7wKD09frXSaZBBFqD2sN55lmwYRNjazAqR369SKYmc4TuG3HI74p+\/IG5QVDc47UXEJt7iSHaUZcqcioS4QAEHbnt1oAlLkDA59\/SgnjBYcDp3FR\/MynB4AyfejIUDg5JoAgJ7Yzg8E9alKMEVyQQeAAeaI4hIoRSRz+dTXFulumBuDE8k9O3\/16kopqcscjg9hxTskEBMk\/ShTgbWXNSKuEYng5GQOCaYFmO0kaAuZAqZCAMcH8PaqxUFwOVIPBH9aeJjkLH1J7mlJQs24jcBn6fjQIsWreW3DkqPvHoKvrcKCHQupPB54NZiRuIMr8y5wfehyiRA8jPXmgDde9iO0MdzEfMV4x+ffg057+HzFZCzMR8xyP5dq56JgU+bBKjKgdcc08MUUsOmRls0AeyeB\/D1ubB\/EGrLuRT\/o8bdD7n1qxq3xOS2mNpCygZxsXge3Sn6DeDWPhva2dq6rLCmw\/N17\/wBa87XwDqNxeySSHYFbc0jHp\/n8KdibnYjxZdTR5S4K7wQVz+tRWPim8gDR3J3HsQc\/5707TPDGmWEQaeVJJmH3mOMVVvzYrcHyAuOg56\/U0gOosfEqTwfZ7jEsUq4KuO1eReL9CXRtYcQL\/oUzFouM49q6X7WlrPEduATyN3OM0\/xlOmoeE0lVf31tICrHrg0wR5vkOu0HKA575pJIgh+Q5z6jp6imA74yuOep4p64WPcfm5wcGkUbfhDw\/HrWtqLllW0hHmyj+8B2z713+sa5YwGOCzESFRjBYAHH9a8w0\/WrnSnle3yDKmx+eCOP8KNQivLjybsoHjlX5W7CgDvX19GCgMocZyu72\/Wsa711WkP7sbe5B4rEudIlsYrW6WVphNzJlCu01fWxzpcsq27NkcMB\/LNAF6PxHbRRkHezKclCccZ9fxq8Nasb3yQq8D5tw65+veuFh0q\/vFlkitpTHHy5GWxUUBNndASpMv8As4wfyoA6jxXYWrWiXUD5Zec4+8PWuMJyAPSu3u1uZ9B8qK3eTIJOFOcehriCCDgjBoBCgqMHBJ+tWrO5minCouSxHA4NaGkeEdc1udY7TT5tp6yyKVRR6kmvRtB+H9qurW1vqF6dSjjX54kZlVW68EHnt6UIGeb65Ks2rStEMbgGYcgcgdKzixchQB1\/Gut8d6Q0Hiu7htY3kRThWUFsDHC\/h0\/Cufi0XVJQRDp87EekZOaYIos7I4B7fw+1IXzkgEL0rYt\/BviK7KLBo925PU7MAfUnpXR2Hwj8RXrKJXtrZSAD5j8j8B\/jSuBryfBzxV5HmLaRJIuCqideR9c\/Tj\/9VU4Pg\/4tvn\/0i2t7QJ086YHP\/fOf1xXrOofEKI7mj4y3y5OO9Zy+LZZk3GbGf9qp1HocZZfAzUmBa61izhbphQzf0rQh+BdqQPtXiIcHOIof8TXQT+KTsKBnzjkg5zVZvElyY1UvgN0JPXmjUNBNP+DvhW3B+1Xl5csOCwIQfkKguPgt4burrzU1a9gjBx5YCnI+p\/wqc67dEKEIGB8w461Xl1W9k3Ybd3GPSiwXN6H4ceCreMbo5pAgx80xxmopPhv4GlwZLaYLnIAnIrlhrN\/DM+5t8PABJ6UsuvMFHzlSRx3FOwrnUxfD7wOAQLWXGMbmmJJrmfEHws0H7DI+m6hLFITlUkcMKgfX7jaoR\/lx8wz3qhPrVxIQrN8pyeKLDuYmi3U3hu\/No8iou3G7PBatG98UTSLLucFievrVC9s0v1c564JJ7fSqf\/CO3j2xkjk3IOMHOaomxFNr10AxDkr0wTUa6wowc8ntn3rOvY5YYwksTFc8sB0NRJC7J8ikcZ3betIDQl1hshsZbvx0\/Cuq8PaPdeM7SbTreRYlkA3StyF6dPXr0rhtK09ry8aPLLEMF2PFen6TrNt4c07y7I\/OTgsOtD8gSIR8AdbGQms6YB25kyf\/AB2hvgLq7gf8TzTkfGCp3HFMuPiVdw3bYkcc4BJP86kfxzqLBJkcsQ3zozfe+n5Gp1GSRfs+aoc79dsCQM4VH5Pbmr1h4Om8Nn7LrSWk1rEV8tocsrkYJzkD2\/Xris5\/iNfCLCzSAnqN1ZV\/43k1eZLWedV3DblqeoG3rN\/pc8o+058peyrn8KpzatpTWgt7NCB1wwxu57fpWNd6dqQbbGY1m4IZuQRn0\/Csy48Pa3c3TzXV8QoOd8j8n6KOB9M0wLthcQQXsv2YyW7uQXVujYH\/ANetZ9Ia8ze3km9V5CDiuSMd7bXixjfcKPvSFQPy5Na\/267S3ETtkdetAG4mtfZLZoY4AgAOGxwc1xt5evZSvdItu5JBKuMnp2NbZBuLbIOBkg8dfxrBvNGEzSSFyABn\/d7UCNAfEW+W3SJSQMfMAoAroPD\/AI32wCHztjZ34zwp6Z9q84hht4Jtk8LyvngZwK6TQtHt9V1eFLe3ZUBHmMo7ewoA+gtJ1izfSl\/doX2hi2zOSRn\/AD9ad\/aRDmVoUAz2UVyc+pppqpaOgijTCjnqMVQn1xEOYpiSTwBU2GjqtR1ZmB8klFJPI471WguX2AtMjEnIBasOHXVmVll2ZTLDa3PWmNfRSyBlTKY5C9uaEhnEyT3Lo6OoZQw69QapSzzRgBCVOegNdY9hBHEHaVRjryQfyrPNtHK5IUADIPNUIx2v7hRw2T7Hg0q6tORvckqTx3281ZuIIokYMMH69KzZlAXA3ZHGRQBbOuSIQoJ57DNSjxDKihSo3DI3HJI\/KslbC5uHYorYPYL6VJD4e1KX5Y4WJz1JA4oAsPrjs3yglR1xTTqbl8E4Q8ZPrUsXh6SFjHPdQxMD0ZhUzWmiwYWbVYiRwcAtz+FAFT7Z5mVU4PXpUnmSYxtLj1qMatodruMKTTEHrjaCOaqSeLZonJtbSJF\/h3fMRTA2re1u5uEhY844Fa1tbXEAxO\/lL33MBXntx4p1qeR9940YPOIwFGPwrLmubm4LNJPI+ezNmlYD1+ceH4xm61GzU45AbOaqXGreDrbJW7WViMbY4\/8A61eSld+Dz+NPijDOjEHbu5oA63VNZtpEli0xDGhfJIHXFYaalKZGU4dF+Zuf5V08WgabJpiRwahbtKwzu3cZPY1z174cns23CRQOmM5z+NAjPuLx5FYt8wPZufrTbe9nUlBI3+yM9KdMIopthbdnh8HHeo55IyQI12ODzg53e9AxJL2R3BLnHvUDSMz7+4PXvWjp2hajqrj7HbNIoGS3QfnXXaP4MskmE2sO0oAGYImwCfc0AR6drd7d6bFPcI7LAwUXCrxnrgnpnpWrLfW+q7VnvPLYAYUKPmHoa6qz1Swt2tdPh06KOxgJItggUOTzyT61W8V+HfDurFZYbabSJmGQ8R3JnHtjFIDmppLJcxrKS2eFIwTWTfTuBHEkShcnoRn059OlU5vDWsmKR4J\/tESciSMnJx7daq6OYJ1lhmZ0mGcrn7xpgbJmaCMHdkEdPrio2uVkjChck+p6VXmjcRgliEHGcVIgWNAc59PzoAgs7VWugCvHv2r0fwxaiDEkSgM\/VsdK4exjUSGTBYjGe1dhpt6FjADBY89c9aBWNnUrWLUGYzZ8zryOK5dNKmknZY8hBkcGti41aISYjcr1AIGSKsWVyrkScZHUNj8aBmQujPblSJHJJ5IGcD\/JrbttNjTBJ2gDglqvpuJ37cEcYA6GiSZQqIwO3BxgY5\/\/AF0AQ3UHhxGKvqkbgHGQD\/Ssq41LwxaxER3UkpHTCf8A6q49YvKPzgleqkdBTUtl8vLKN+fTg0Ab15rujRNmOwklyOCWAzWAfE6xO7Wum2wUH+P5sU57AEbi5wozjbwD6e9Yd1b7JS0WPcH1\/wA5oAtyeLdSALxvFFubHyIP0rNutX1C5ffLcSsGPzDdVFjuYhlyobGMciiWQbfkyV7kj+VMCN7iR8sd3J4JP1p2\/wAw5VSO5zTTtMYQjGW69qTYCSA52Y54JzQIarMAf4l6c9qGUEcDAHrTfmQAY3D2pxfIVf4cdaBikrtAHp0Pao93G0gFc9e9KTgHavP0pgJCjHI780AK3OAOnen5UYKn6e1MPzkA9OgowAOB\/wDWpAOFw8SskbMoPv1pDNLNzJLIxHAJPSjYSBgHpyDSlBtHXB6nPQ0AV9rFvUmuy8C+Ehr9w13eqV06A4Yjje3XaK5PZkEJ0JFe4xW8Oi+HrTT4v3flwjeB\/ExHJ\/OgCbUJ7WztWtrCFYooxt+UY7VyMV04vGfjZnkNVm5leSJ0804J7jmsq43xgBDkAc9qAN29vI5IfkYRuOdrcism91\/UYrdUZDwcdOKoHUSsoMowpOVWo7\/U2u1wmAh6oAMA\/X8qTAopq91FMWDYVjkFT\/MVFOYL6Yz48qZfmDp3qtM+WAI6+3eksLCW5maRUYKDj8KYG0+oC6j2ErnHXbwaoebIHPdc4NWpNMKKTsIz3FV3i8ptqjIPSgCxBcyKoZeFBG7P+fatCK5cjEZZGJyOeKpQxh1UEEKe9bNnbqNwjHzD0HrQBXt5bh2K7fx759a3NLMkWJCm4FgCTzT4rdlQbVAXb6d6sRHyFXAynr\/n60Aba3DbdgXcWPHr+lOd0K4LLyP7vSswzu65ClUzgkA9aabuNMkgnc3r0\/z6UAcyXiICOgOMdO2aqu2y4MiDMecOvAwKjWRBGQAS\/Iy3TpzxUL+ZAu4pkEbiR\/doAtXErLEVjkYg9iOhrHuNygkShnIOQMj8\/ep5zJ5fmu37snAxgfpWbdkRyKV+YlQw28jB\/wD1CgDPkZjMdnUHJBpE3lgTkrnpk0u5owWAzg\/SmBikO0fMueaYiYxl2CqSMDGAK0otJmuSkUOCChOQuDx2PqarwvE7YfKR4xgAZz6mnvdAOyW7bFUg4PWkMqT2zxyNAwAZCfwI96qMGzggEL7dKviWQsZFbEjHJx2qMwlU3BQM9qAKmDwTkqTyB3pdvGBkn0q0sW5VyCMc0vk8HC\/jTAgETYwcc8jinJGS2WGQeKupCWGWPToBUm1AgR8hu3GRQBnMhHyg8d6Upsx0Oener7QbxtUdOc+tMa22sMDDY59qQGf5e0gnPBHtXpGta9HI0OHwskasN3fIzXB\/Zy8mdvGM7hyDXRvbQanocMgP7yFfLJ9COn9KALVvMZXEY5zzVt1O0gqcd8965zT7w21z5E4xjhTntXUJJvhAK4yOucUAYV5Gsm5Qgz1HqKy1hCPt3EE8YK10tzGF3PjLNyT7\/wCTWbLEokYqg3frQBoaRpdlLEm9lDLnB7mtSWxW3jBiUA9jjrXMw3D2jgDpuznpW\/Fqqyoqt24oArzjIwy8E9KzLmFQS69e3FblwFnX5AcemOtZ06hVBUZyPqaAKVqS5K4xz6d66O0cbDuRGUgdODXNRMEfbzjI6dq6HTydijB2j+LigDRYvGpyee3PB9\/8+lDSLtHBBPYf560MQcAk8DoTg5qtJIEZlVQDjIAGAPr60ASSTPF8gcjjGG6e2az5rrYxVjt4yRTriR2IcdFXHHr35rGuJlDksD8\/dfT0oEUZbplmYqu7na3bBrZt2sX05\/nInMf8OThsnv6HiuSN9ELeaA7lJbJ459jW3JozpoNpqccokjIzIFbGDz+dAzOup5BGyRvxu53HpVTzU8vnCv8AdQgHJ\/EdsVWupyX+VsL3BHSlkMsdqmArIeccZA\/pQASSArt4YfzoeNEiXaSpIyec4+tVmbMZVfvE9PUUgXaMnOSN3AxQBcaYOgUqCVXO9eOf61GkoZzHKB065pEjfyC3Q5+5j+tI2YsMf4vvDAyPTmgCwgAI+Td9DVySeKVVRIxGyE+pyarJBLND+5ViSewySPpVuDSb+eMeTY3MjkZ4jY\/pQBUdtzhcYI9B0qaMBn+fJHNaNp4Q8SXQbydDvmOf+eLYNbdv8NvF1xAFXQ5hzkiQquPzNAHOoVDhcbvw7VLI0TqFA+UHPTke9dhZfCPxdMWWSyhhU\/xPOp\/lV2D4N680rGa+sIGzj77Nn8hRdAebyTKs6ryQe2OlK7xhQckHsTXqEHwTmMz\/AGvxBaRk8HYjHP5kYq3H8HtDXAvfEMrbR\/yyUDP60rgeP+fnA4zjk9Kv6HqcEN29q7oFlOME969Sf4aeA7IBZtTuXHX5rgDNZWpaF8NtNgD20c0swOd5mLAGmgOS1PS0kTemQ45Wn6ZdsF+z3Bww9a1IJ7e8tMxHG0kY7Y7Vk36CQ5Aw46GgRtbFkTaw4P8AFjFUJYSsh+XI9D3qPSNV8\/day\/LKhxj1rVaINHgjjPLUhmRcW2Y8heexrLjn+zTANkZIrppbdFQMvXB59a5XVYvLmMm3OfagZv292HjYHBBPUDmklfLbGAI55rB0+8DpsI6HnIraIQpvUYz+VMRQusxOHUA+471qabeiVdmdpA5JOP8APWqUirJgNkHsfes4x3UEjNGu9M8igDrpJSw+\/gj6kGq73DbiDJ8pzkbutYcWq4jxtJ\/vDmrBv1kiCgEnOc0AX523jHBY\/KSDwfSsm94YKxXIHfg\/Wj7Vx8gycdRzVS5m8whnzk4AoA6X\/hR\/jC5LA21pCxxy8+4f+O5\/lXV6Z8MPEsGiSaZdz2aRyHbuGW2jvx+XSrN58c7QkvFbbULcBnLcfgKxLj4yTtCsqMCjNjA45z05FLUehZHwF83LN4ggQAg4WIk8fjVmL4HaSdouPEU2R12Rgc\/ia5y8+LF7LdmaG1SPqTuJOR+dLa\/EDWPEF7IkX7tvK8zMX3RyBzn60ai0Ous\/g94Nt4pBc6tdztu4bzFXH4AVcs\/hn8PLFi0sU08hAA3zsR+Q4rx6\/wDGuuI0tqzFZ0Yjcmcn3PNRy+KNZSJLppJHt3QfKMAjjnnHrmgD3OPR\/h3preaujW7Y4BZd38+KuJqXgGzcgWGmpznH2dX\/AC4P6V86prF1Na\/6TLOU2EfM3GD0wPxqEXKyuywzzlVAZcsf1osM+jx458I2LHy0tYznotsBVWX4qeH7JiI5Cp6\/JDivnN2f97OzuyEjhjnFL9oQxg+QW478CiwXPdrv4yWcY3QvKwPJwtZtz8adjExRzlP98fzryBNptkLpnP3mU\/lTkjVgWToozz2osFz0dvjJqUoJWOTaGw2XxWfP8TdbmkPkyeWOoAPQVw4Q8FJMktllK8Y7VPtAYmNlySApx3707Cubt18QdceXBnlG1xk561mXnibVpwTNdS4JqrsFzc7dxeOP78g9OmRnrUN5AAgT0Pr0oAje8u2XbJM7n1J6V2\/hn4PeI\/ElqL24kSytn5TzicuD3CjoPrVf4deHbTxD4ttIrsBreAefIh\/jC4wv0yRX05CWSLy0CqgGBt7D0oegI+c9X8HX\/hCX7Nc3UM5kUlGjB+Ue\/v1rmQtxJMQI2J78f5zXrfxAtWuvEgYybQIhgN0Fcna6eUmDuwUL0HUmi4WOPutLulEThJIps7lbpW3YahLLCILxPLnXjkfe9xWrcZmuckZQHAx04rM14w3GnpztlikzG68EEUXAvHa0ZVgfxrmdbh2wuNmfTPWreja8l+PsshAmj4we\/uK1bq0W4gIYEn1pDPOre5aCYKehIzXTWcplJBX5evFOg8NtdXDqke7PLHpXoHhrwfFp9uLi8PygZCdc0CMbSfDkup4lcLDCON7dD9PU121h8KLOeFmvridd3REUL+JyDXVaBo6v5d7cxBQo\/cx4+77\/AFroiQCR6D1pgeWTfBjTQT5eoXQPuBiud1L4Tava7m07UlkXssigZr3Nz3B69RVeUBj1OKAPlvULHW9AkK6npbNEDy8eWUj69qI30rU4w0MohfurLivpa7s4LiFkkQMp52sMivDviR4Ai02CXWdKHkbDuljQ4BB7igR5oA8wkicAlSMk0gDJKsTxr5bAnaB\/L8q6y28PxxeHpb25xDOrAID16jOf1\/Kse4to59jxAJKin8TRcDKkAJCgHHfHOK3fBDqfEYtsPiRSu0GuamybgoQwYcAg1ueAtp8ZWAdtoLFemeowP1NFwaK3iwqniW9jiDKqvjBPPQVY03XII9PSzu1GApCPjOPTNP8AG1hJF4muWRWdHw25V4ye1ZH9laiLYN\/Z8zK5+VhGSRTs9xnQXyxC2iiXaQQDuHvVO+txZwJPA6usgO35RkduRVtdJv71bPyLG4ChAsgdTkEcdD1rXvPBuvTwKlvpzkgY21NwOS0+QMGibn+7u7k0t0yyt5EUPlv\/ABheSceldlYfDLxFPbGM2SJISGy7YINWLb4U+KHuZHWGBDjbuMhbdnqeM4ougPOJJ5YWMceQqEjirdvdn7GI24+b73PPHQ16OvwQ1t3Cm8s4hncSSx\/pV+P4J3sluIptasosNnARjn8ad0FmeVLNuYqoG88+1WJ7K\/WJJzu8vrlSMivVLT4IGG5M8uvROAMbBCf8avv8I7SZ1E+tyIqjAWNP8g0rhY83itreDQYjKiLeztniQE7efT8K52884Tr5coDHuT1Fe2Wnwo0K3LG61u8nJ+UFiBgelXB8KPBkcplmurpmUdDN2\/AUXCxwHwekb\/hYC5mRT5LIYyeX5HIr6ajBSAtlSfrXnOkeE\/Bfh3UV1LTlCXQXCyNISRn0z3roTq+nuHWW4Qnpy+DQ2Ox5n4411Z\/G01vGRsRVUkHpgDNY1xqiKu0HLAc9K9N+yeEJJJJJYYXlkbcWaTJz+J4qF5fB1tucw2jsP4crz+lAjyabVY5LUsBg8\/KetctNq0n2R0mVy7OxB9uB\/Svem1zwbZykNaWi4OCpCmmN418G25x9m08gdMIp\/mKAPmmH7UJxc2ySblbcGRScV6p4Svn8QaWSYWMkRxIAmB9Qa7\/\/AIWV4Tt1fyrO3K9\/LgXH8qqyfFjR0j2wWW0MM8RAfyoGYlsyW1yAUZAWC4C+\/U16Fo66dfXEcdu6ny+WDHO4D2ryDxN8TXuJ5obS1jjCHhsAn9Kj+Gnim6bx7bS3kqiOVGhIPHJ5B+tNITPpMfKoAwOKa3PQDpS5BQYIO4dRTD8vGDQIGOR0BAFRN0wAMdDx3qQkAdPfrTW+7jH4igCtLxxgVyXjxYf+EQ1EzqAohOS34V2DYHA79xXm3xi1RLTwZNbqf3lwwQc8470AXpfCvhOBvKMgKIcKDJjB+tZ8Hh3wDp8haJE8xieTJuPpXjdzqd1FZSObmQupyCRwTVK51CW68p7W5bJOXDHp\/wDWFKwz2yez8CWcrH7LbbieScEmpJr3wbbeS1paQLKo+Vo0Ab614BczXDyxrNLIrYx1zz61s+HpJf7TinfNw8TqFTONwHXn8adgPXovGOjBpI5LKFliGd3kAk8jjpSr490iGUeXaqD1A8sVwmvwrLE1zbWxiO7D7pB8vX8azNMR7HxAkkr7pNuVO7cCP5UgPSLv4hW0F1JEbNSyNhhgFlOM1nT\/ABY+0XmIbJxGVBDN9M8npmvOfEl1c6hq19ebiI4wqgYxx0H\/AOusO0v5LaGSErkHnmiyC7PYZfijK06xw2ZYtyqsx5FUH+KWrB0CQJHuwduTlR+fvXJywtLoxZUVZfKEiOv05\/StPw\/pdnpfhKTVtRCyTzBvKD849Pz5\/OgLmi\/xT16USSxgZRxgFuo65zUTfETxM8kbRu4D8gr\/AD6VymiKE1GeVbfdhGLDqMY9K6Lda3MVupmR1BGwIm1hnGR9BQFxbnx54sSRyJ5lIbIORyPWorfxN4z1C4dYHmYrznj\/AArPu7NNb8WQWFtNshTCyjPHy\/zr0S4uJLQpDp8CHcuFZV79Of8AGmB55deLfEkKSC6uGikEm0hnAPv2rKufF+u+a6rqL7ByOnQ1r+N9OL3Uc2dty6lriMDIGAMMPryPwrh9o3rjkHpQBuR+I9YmYpJdykuMqcgGrSXepyWLyyXtwZMjaFbOfUVW1\/SPsFtauoP+rG72rb8D6VFLZ3mp3z\/uYsKgJzk884\/GhgYjz31tbiW5jmYMeHYVmPcSszSB88jK9q9X8S2tu3ha5eRclAHUKOnavHQRk5\/A0ASyTyScu7H61G8jPgE03rxSsFBwpz70DJLVsXC+\/FdVYsJNiMmM9fpXJIcFWBGQc811mn3MJEcqsDu4b29qESylrMY+1\/IoU5OagsYpIZY3V\/3hIZSvaptdkf7WHAIHTjirWmZ+zLJn5sUwPTPCHxHk0147LWZ3NueFmAyVPuK9fsdas9Qj82C4jnjYcMhzXyu8DXM2d4AyM8V1GmXV3o8Sz2V2yMzY2KeoxzxSA+jFkSVSUJ4\/Skc8YOPyrxvSPizB9nYX7gKrBRPCc5Puo5xXcab4vtL2BZYJ4rhTyWjbGPwpAdJK4QEt2HftXz78YtZ+2a3Bp8ZGyJfMcL6n\/wCtXst7r8f2OUmByw6kj9fpXzxf2r6vr1\/fTsWzLyT\/AAjsKaBmtEtpPoF\/aLKjESDbhPukgE4P14\/D3rjtPWC2mnMy5En7lNuO\/Uj9Kfok9yZJrQH5pVDbi3TB7\/nVTUIpLTUESQbVQ5DDkE9zSGOnhS0uWSUdtqNjIArW8I3kEeuBHPyBTtOev+cVoXGp6HY6fHBc2f255uZJMbSmR2NZekaTDLqMzxyuEjUvGQASwxwPamBcuJNQ1LxVKsSyXRn+URoucDsAOgFXpvBPjTTbcyppu6NOpDKcZPHfmut+EM8UMl+b0qbl2BUKuTtAzgV6fNr1n5D4ZBjhd3X9aVxpHzsml6m+mXT3EMgaRkyhXklc8\/SuYu0aKVWMRRh1BHFfSFxJbpZve6cYxI3yyKpwF7g4\/OuM8Vra+JtHa3ENuNTiXcZEABPXii4WPOIPENz5MVvIFEL8MR1I9P5VcvL\/AM\/QLRLdnJjkZZEznB+npx+lc7JZXdtCHcbfm+7nJ+tRQ3UsErSKxDN1oEeueG7a0FmSTGZXUK+SM4POK5DxAqWXinMEoRW3KBu4X6\/jWPp2t38KytFL82QcEjms68vZrq5NzIx8185z2pgTWd5cafqfmAN5u\/DDPJz1+ten6d4rszaIzTKJD8vIPB9K8ouLhpZlm+7JtGcc9utPW7mNg8fybQwyx+9znp+VIDo9c8SRXWtXEod3jETQKVxzkcH865q0mjjmSWVA6xHdt9T2H51W3HbjPGc0qvhWUjIP6UAdsL9W0OK4vyHE7fMMdfYVPpmqaX566cgdI2cGMNxkniuPae5ubOESFmhtvX7o9B9a2JtbgguYJ7KzaN1AyrqTnnPegDu\/HJjs\/BsiqdrOyqozyTkf0rx2tbXdeu9buA07EIh+VAePrisrBHagEJRRSgEnABJ9qBiVf0268uZYn+6x4OcYqoLeZukMh+impU06+kOI7O4Y+ixMf6UAdLJapcwTvINwQZGD14PHFZdiZ55UghYKrMEUbvU8VJZ6L4lljaO30jUXR+CRbPj88Vv3+ja5HpkFpDod0ksRU+f5LKx4ORxTuTY1DHovhmyMt5dR3F4V4gXnJ+n9TXDalq81wH2yFTJ1VTwq+la4+Hvi+9ZZV0q6dj\/HJ8v\/AKEavQfB\/wAXTDMlvbQZ7SzjP6ZpDSOIQMsW8Ehc8AdzUtrqN3YzLNa3LxupyNpxXptr8D9UliAutXtYSOcIjPj+VaFr8DrVGzda3NIB2igC\/wAyadwsYui\/E29Wykt79I5G2cSH9ciuT1LxJ50f2ayTy4HYvIT1Zjj8uletf8Ka8PrhnkvW9t4Gf0q9a\/Cvw1HKkn2GRgDgB5CR+WaQ7G1D8GvC1hNvga8HQHM2dwHY8dOKZd\/CLw\/fMvmNceWhBADD\/Cr8vxS0PYWR125xlmPI\/Kom+IlmUDx28rKRnKIWFAFS8+D\/AIb1Bh9pN2WH3SrhRj8qtad8KfD2jxyJafaB5gwxZ9x\/Os+5+LNjHN5fkSMQB\/A3HfHt1pkPxVtrpHMVucI209cg\/hQBt2Xw90fTN32IvEzP5jNnLFvXPWlufAuk3UgMstyTnOA+AT+VVE8ZyTRxzC0m2MOG8l8Gon8cRRzyRPE4ZOv7tsce9AXNeLwVpMMBhBkKkYOW9sVVh+HPhqFmYW8hZj94yGqqeOPMiaeO3doh1YRkgZ+lVZfiZYRFA7Af9sWoC5rf8K18Jbwz6cj+zO2P50p+G\/gvLE6FaFj1LZ\/xrm5PiZYSXQgjvGJZvlURYzz0yfrTJ\/ihp0LEtbSN6\/IKAudPF4H8I2J3x6LZgZ\/uZz+dKfC\/hYtzodixz3hU\/wA648fFuwMa4gkCMeDgY9O5ps3xcto5tiadL833fmAzQB2D+H\/DoHlnQrFsdAYVpsHhzQIyf+JHYL6fuF5+nFcVcfFkw\/c0xsbQxDH27VRj+MU00e9dJ+Qc5ZqLBc9I\/sTRA3GkWRb3gU\/0qUabp0a7BpViAOceSnH6V5M\/xi1Aeft05QIz0ZjVCX41a2z4Sxgj9Bk0Aexrp9jHlBp1oSx\/55KR\/KlGnWYOTY227uPKGP5V4fJ8ZPETuWjit1HoEzVWT4s+KpiWWSFQBk7YqAPeDo9qwJ\/s6yOef9Sv+FNXR7EcnTrUr\/1yWvErX4j+LLyLKXCb+AoC4yPwq+fG3ilUAS4Afbz+7BOadguewpZaZGeLC1Jz\/wA8l\/wqdEs0BjGn2w9f3a14jH4u8TPE0z3zKATxtHP6Vh3PxA16U\/JqMoPcrgYpWFc+ifJtYm3COFOxAQU57qzgGTMi8dlr5cufFWuzsfM1Sd8981v+APD+pePfE0djcX062MS+bdv5h\/1YI+Ue5Jx+vagZ9H2Ma6hAs0EoaAk\/PjggcHFX49PtEO87Wb1J6UEW1raxWluoigjjCRogzgDjFRrFMuWWWQ46AkUhln7Orc5IHaozbJnlST70xhcg5GGFOa8lTAaLco75zQMDApOCePSnNbpxg0sdxFOhDApnocDmpFEHZ8D1PWgCp5CjlwCc4p6xrkYwP51Y8uJuBKC3fNJtRSAAaYj45k1W4RHguGMuWDc8V6L4I8Sw3lpBpsyEyFSq7R0xgZNeSMxZiT1NeqfCfSofNOpzHkKQue3OP6GhkljWPCmravrqRgm2gkIHmIMlvQe1dHoXgX\/hF5Jp57hrosoyrgHGM+nfmusuruG2iaVCMIPy4rlx4kNyZljclE4OT3NAHV6J4lsbi4bT5YYI0QYXj7x\/z\/KpdegEFrJPZxx7zyCwzj3rwS81a90zxZHJG5KySA7e3WvV9T8TwxaPFKX+R8DGe+KLDucdrHxDudU0prCWJbWWJwkuxQolUd\/Y9DiuO1HVIxBsW4aSR1I9xWhqcI1\/xBJbafAxa4iYn03Adq4iaO4trl4ZVdZkO1lYc0xHY2dgZdGdLl5HmR8o6jkdM49elZ9xbwvNFawXckl24wI2G3YcHqTxWxpmpxQ2doZGARVBfPY96yZvC2sXM76nDGpjaXepDfNjPWgDQ0qztrjT5bUOxljDIwbgk46\/SsyKdIdajt5vmj+8C38J9P0ro9A06fVFvbyIGOeECEt2lPfH04riNZWeLWZQ6lJlOCPQ0kwsa19qMfnCVnJiB2gBR8w71dsptEmtPs1mHM8mf9YSoXPqTXITyh1hTkBFwc+uSTXaeGvDkULQ390+FJyVPAAoYEWtWNhYJFDBdrdnyiJpBkqG9ietcnKJYlj+bII4G2ur8ZaO9nrBuLJGexdgdq5IBrPisYpRbI5G9jtUMcYyeM0ICfwn4ZbxLfDToplhZhvdiudq\/wCNetWfwV023ti7alMzbCDlVAJ\/wq74O8J2vh6zhnyss7HezjoT\/wDWrsdQuLi3tpT5bH92SuOnTihsEeC3ejw6FrE9oo3eS4Bkxzzgj6VvRtDckbYEdyOWYDiqN2oE+sS3bHznnjkXdnkHqKdG8yW+5HXHUZ6gUAUdXjgt2K7VDy8hQMBcetcDdxob4hPl7nHpV\/UL+e41uRpJcKmeScA\/5NZUkoEjFvvZ6g9smmBCyqJcE4XvX0b8EvD7af4WuNTlTEupuCmeAsSZ2j8SSfyryb4d+CJPGOvlZtw062IkunUcEZ4QH1P8q+nLO2kt4BbWaxQ28AVYVHTaBjb7UmNF9oYxljknHUGozGVAKE5+uDQjA4WfIcHld1THCjgbhikMqv5hYDByaGi6ZHJ7CrUmNg5CjHOOtQSSCLICYzyOnNMCDy1AMbpn8uBTWtVYBVJAHXtig3Gw8jAbocVMsuUCsMKfTjNAFV4hGcCXHORtbOKaiOpyCwPc44NW2BBOI1APIJ60u4YC46859aBnxKRkkgcV6n4Av4bbw\/IjSF3TJUA4xnnH51JH8BvEy7le5s0OOSrFh\/L+lXNK+C\/iSz8zbqNtEW4JwxGP8aLkkE+rx6vpeoospivYMlSGJLDHSsnwbdNcXz2bRed5gyTuI6V1+mfBTUYpLqW51uNfNBChAQM+prZ0L4ZDSI3X+0SZWPMyg5NAHlfjqC2g1uytrYt55BaQZyFyeAD+H61BpbR3WvrY6gzmCNRiLeVBNetD4M2N1q41B9TmMy\/NtY8E\/wBKZcfC7w\/q2ukTajKt5GgLEMOAOnGKLhY5yF7Xw34xsri6tI47aWJkjdVyFyaz\/iLpMGpajDf6aAZAv70jkNzx+lex2HgDw+qxLdD7YkIxGJDuFb0GlaPBEbdLGAxg5wUB5pXHY+O7yPUA8lusFwsW7OAh+au7svEJg8IskiSRugwodTmvo3+xtJVxL\/Z9qD6mFSf5VG+naUwwbC2Iz08pcfyobA+VdD8T3llNDa+S3kDJIAIJJ5ySKbq9wL67kuEs5Azdzz+tfUq6Jo6FpBptruPBIiX\/AApsi6JAhhbT7YgckGJTn9KLg0fIdnYzahNJOVYBGHyqhNdNqOqagulW0P2OYhSMkRH5gPwr6LS50JCWTTLcL0+WJQP5U\/8AtrSIFINpEqYPy7Rii4WPALvxnbahAsKW6eb\/ABBmxzjFczqTzahexswEXTGz09a9Y8W+HPDmprPcabpm27kbcGjIrmYvC99b6U8L2M8tw2QgJXgUXBnTWviSy0bSLOZZmNrhFm3Nkhj3Fep6dqtlqsImtp45oGG7PY14f4a8DeJAsyXlxbRWrqcWzpv3H644\/OtPw14T8TeGtQM639qlmzEGPJPFGghPi9DHaX1tPbKIVlJDbT1we9czb36tp3lM43eX8rZ4JxXd694Tj8SXCG\/1mNMA4wDgZrNT4eeFbVyL3xDIVAwArAAGmI8gvozI7bcA7sNzmt3QPBU2v3VpY2DbrqZt0srfdhjHVvw969LHhj4baTbiaKe4upn6ZctuJ\/Cu78LeGodEs5ZxB5M10oBT\/nmnYfXmi47Fjwxomn6Lp0Wm6VHs063HzSNy1xJ0Lk\/UV0fnEZYKMA9Omarx26RKpCsVxwucACozLIW4AC9gppDLgmiuTtbOT7VHLHPH9xsjoB61A3mIAQu5fftU8d5nhgNp6eppgIdkiDczI+ME4pqwssexJA2O\/FTGGKcl1kKMeuT\/ADFMjge33AfMCevUYpAIsLNgBd2O9SNC20DaGUVOJgABtVcjt1NRy3KgfJlgOuB0pgNwFIGAf6UFORwKrS3Q\/gjfB9DnNV0nUHaQ4cno1Azmr74maErEw3KFd2AcnB5rFuvippkaSZuMlG2\/L0\/M8frXgWmbbucxugOBuyTU+vW+26giiwN0YdlHRc8f0p2Iue4j4iyyaYLg2kv2fOd\/bA6ms4\/FaC4nEdpbN0yW3cfnXFf2nFb+CXiaUJJtEO09fr+X86xPD1hd38iIjKIerH8aEDZ6k3xAvdyKx8rzUYqWI4Irz63+IepNrkl5FDGSRteQ\/wAS9B9OcU7xJcW9prVrapOMRW7luP4sHGfrXKaXNEllqML4DSRDaT2wf\/1UAmd3B8W9Whudoh6nAANdnYfEy51HRfPgijM8aZKYO7OcV4AZG7Hn1rvvCEC2Wh3eq3coiieNlQHuc4H60mB7FB4r1ibTY5poPLlI3Mh6VIviPVJ5BtiAH4Vy2jeKLO6tZNNnY+bsBXnqD6flXW2NnCyBs4AHQmhDNS1vL+bhpAueDgDFc\/44kvNH0a61W1PmSwID5b+nr9K2pZ4LNVXnHUmsPX9QtdXtZLJ5CRP8ufRcHNAHn8Xj\/wAQz6HLew2lnGojZioBJAAOW5rhrjxvrN2GV5lQueWXPH4ZxWt4PuUGv3OkXrA206SIuFPDY6D8M\/pXIajbR2t3JDFJvVXYflQB6HoPiPV7S0M3kWQRDuBYEsAe5INar+KtY1EAwy2ZAG7KngcVxK36ReEmVs7jiIf5\/D9an06\/W00uPI7YAHc0xXOki8Sag8rwyX6edG2HVWGFHrXOahrPiCXWhaw3kkccnzRsMHK+tY2jRT3mtSMnJPLn6mrd1MB4gJU71jjESMP7w6\/rmgDYtrHW9VupYxqkpVEz+5IJNUdS8O6mGczTXjnPHmZA\/Guv8NnTtG0ma6nlf7VINqLGvOeevbr\/ACq8jjx5qVnolkRv2+fdTkcRRA4P1bngepFICz8IPBQuZBrupBporVyLRW\/ik6F8HsvQe+fSvaygTLzBeB8vNQWVna6XY29jZIsFtAgjjUH2\/wA81I0EUjZLMDnpnrQUNMgm4RT9WHFOaPauNqkClK4Ajjwq+tIsCjlmyT0oAYkx2fd49DUcjh2wFyD+lXSiYAB4ApCqhcL19aQFZXdCBtyD3xVyIoy43qDjgbu9VTHvzlgB39TXKeK7660uJZtPYEREO6nqQTQB2M0rH5CgZx90jtWK2pywXID4Q7sEEcEU3SdXSW2SSVyXkQEq45U9eoqxqVnHdx5BUttyp\/8Ar0xE0t3NbBbhIVML9R1xT\/PtbpQy5Hp7VzGn6tNa3P2acllJCtGTxj1HpUkKfZpS0MwMTk7UPBHPagZ\/\/9k=\"]]],\"error\":null,\"project\":{\"avatar_colour\":\"#AA2216\",\"avatar_image_url\":null,\"name\":\"Default\",\"id\":\"project_83ffdc5c2cd54c5b95d8077a3cc15ec7\"}}"
```

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
<?php
$step=$_GET['step'];
$subject=$_GET['subject'];
$action=$_GET['action'];
$actionlist = array (
  0 => 'going for a hike',
  1 => 'wearing a backpack',
  2 => 'practising archery',
  3 => 'swimming in the ocean',
  4 => 'tending to vegtables',
  5 => 'watching for birds',
  6 => 'doing parkour',
  7 => 'using a metal detector',
  8 => 'winning the stanley cup',
  9 => 'looking through a telescope',
  10 => 'riding a horse',
  11 => 'driving a car',
  12 => 'collecting stamps',
  13 => 'visiting a mueseum',
  14 => 'rock climbing',
  15 => 'cleaning the kitchen',
  16 => 'playing an xbox',
  17 => 'baking a pie',
  18 => 'making dinner',
  19 => 'taking a photograph with a camera',
  20 => 'knitting a sweater',
  21 => 'practicing calligraphy',
  22 => 'on the bridge of the U.S.S Enterprise',
  23 => 'riding on a train',
  24 => 'playing with lego ',
  25 => 'stepping on lego',
  26 => 'doing a jigsaw puzzle',
  27 => 'playing tennis',
  28 => 'playing table tennis',
  29 => 'editing wikipedia',
  30 => 'shopping a store',
  31 => 'making coffee',
  32 => 'scuba diving in the ocean',
  33 => 'being angry online',
  34 => 'waiting for their bookclub',
  35 => 'to chill and study for exams with',
  36 => 'winning the world series',
  37 => 'out for a walk on a sunny day',
  38 => 'enjoying a rainy day',
  39 => 'playing chess',
  40 => 'playing checkers',
  41 => 'repairing their bathroom',
  42 => 'repairing their kitchen',
  43 => 'building a model car',
  44 => 'reading a newspaper',
);
$subjectlist = [
  0 => 'Muhammad Ali',
  1 => 'Elvis Presley',
  2 => 'Babe Ruth',
  3 => 'John Lennon',
  4 => 'Bob Dylan',
  5 => 'Marilyn Monroe',
  6 => 'Michael Jackson',
  7 => 'Michael Jordan',
  8 => 'Al Capone',
  9 => 'Paul McCartney',
  10 => 'Charlie Chaplin',
  11 => 'Marlon Brando',
  12 => 'Frank Sinatra',
  13 => 'Alfred Hitchcock',
  14 => 'Johnny Carson',
  15 => 'Jackie Robinson',
  16 => 'Walt Disney',
  17 => 'David Bowie',
  18 => 'Steve Jobs',
  19 => 'Bruce Lee',
  20 => 'Joe Namath',
  21 => 'Bill Murray',
  22 => 'Elton John',
  23 => 'Denzel Washington',
  24 => 'Elizabeth Taylor',
  25 => 'Bruce Springsteen',
  125 => 'Lion',
  126 => 'Hedgehog',
  127 => 'Coyote',
  128 => 'Possum',
  129 => 'Dolphin',
  130 => 'Meerkat',
  131 => 'Crocodile',
  132 => 'Otter',
  133 => 'Raccoon',
  134 => 'Hyena',
  135 => 'Jackal',
  136 => 'Fox',
  137 => 'Monkey',
  138 => 'Panda',
  139 => 'Deer',
  140 => 'Black Leopard',
  142 => 'Kangaroo',
  143 => 'Tiger',
  144 => 'Cheetah',
  145 => 'Zebra',
  146 => 'Giraffe',
  147 => 'Jaguar',
  149 => 'Wolf',
  153 => 'Snake',
  154 => 'Eagle',
  155 => 'Vulture',
  156 => 'Elk',
  159 => 'Owl',
  160 => 'Ox',
  161 => 'Alligator',
  162 => 'Panther',
  163 => 'Parrot',
  164 => 'Flamingo',
  167 => 'Rhinoceros',
  169 => 'Beaver',
  171 => 'Walrus',
  172 => 'Toad',
  173 => 'Starfish',
  174 => 'Shark',
  175 => 'Reindeer',
  176 => 'Rat',
  177 => 'Rabbit',
  178 => 'Mole',
  179 => 'Lizard',
  180 => 'Leopard',
  181 => 'Koala',
  182 => 'Jellyfish',
  184 => 'Frog',
  186 => 'Bat',
  188 => 'Badger',
  189 => 'Arctic wolf',
  190 => 'White-Tailed Deer',
  195 => 'Turtle',
  196 => 'Tree frog',
  205 => 'Skunk',
  206 => 'Scorpion',
  207 => 'Salamander',
  208 => 'Potoroo',
  209 => 'Poison Dart Frog',
  210 => 'Piranha',
  211 => 'Parakeet',
  214 => 'Moth',
  215 => 'Moose',
  216 => 'Marmoset',
  218 => 'Macaw',
  219 => 'Lemur',
  220 => 'Kodkod',
  221 => 'Kingfisher',
  222 => 'Jay',
  223 => 'Iguana',
  224 => 'Hummingbird',
  225 => 'Hornbill',
  226 => 'Hawk',
  227 => 'Grouse',
  228 => 'Flying Squirrel',
  229 => 'Finch',
  230 => 'Electric Eel',
  232 => 'Chameleon',
  233 => 'Catfish',
  235 => 'Capybara',
  237 => 'Butterfly',
  240 => 'Brocket Deer',
  241 => 'Bobcat',
  242 => 'Bass',
  243 => 'Bandicoot',
  244 => 'Baboon',
  245 => 'Bison',
  246 => 'Red panda',
  249 => 'Worm',
  250 => 'Whydah',
  251 => 'White-eye',
  252 => 'Whistler',
  253 => 'Weasel',
  254 => 'Viper',
  258 => 'Tamarin',
  259 => 'Takin',
  260 => 'Stick Bug',
  261 => 'Starling',
  262 => 'Spectacled Bear',
  263 => 'Snow Leopard',
  264 => 'Raven',
  266 => 'Newt',
  273 => 'Guinea Pig',
  274 => 'Giant Panda',
  277 => 'Falcon',
  278 => 'Echidna',
  286 => 'Cougar',
  295 => 'Chinchilla',
  296 => 'Chamois',
  297 => 'Caribou',
  300 => 'Buzzard',
  301 => 'Bulbul',
  302 => 'Brown Bear',
  303 => 'Boa',
  304 => 'Blue Sheep',
  305 => 'Bird',
  306 => 'Beetle',
  307 => 'Bee',
  308 => 'Black Bear',
  309 => 'Mountain Cat',
  310 => 'Salamander',
  311 => 'Alpine Chough',
  312 => 'Alpaca',
  313 => 'African Wild Dog',
  314 => 'African Buffalo',
  315 => 'Accentor',
];
?>
<form action="generator.php?">
  <label for="generate">Choose a subject</label>
  <select name="subject" id="subject">
        <?php
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($subjectlist as $item){
         echo "<option value='$item'>$item</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  <select name="action" id="action">
        <?php
        // Iterating through the product array
        foreach($actionlist as $item){
         echo "<option value='$item'>$item</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
  <input type="hidden" id="step" name="step" value="2">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
<?php
echo "Step is".$step;
echo "subject is".$subject;
if ($step == 2)
{
echo "if check passed";
echo "subject is".$subject;
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();
$promptmade = $subject." ".$action;
echo "the prompt is ".$promptmade;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.pipeline.ai/v2/runs');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 45);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n    \"pipeline_id\": \"pipeline_API Value",\n    \"data\": [\n        [\"'echo $promptmade;.'\"],\n        { \"num_images\": 1, \"seed\": -1, \"diversity\": 3}\n    ]\n}");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization:=';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result,true);
echo "<br><br><br> JASON: ".$json['result_preview'];
print_r(json_encode($result,$newarray));
header("Content-type: image/png");
$data = $json['result_preview'];
echo '<br><br><br> here is your image: <img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $data . '" />';
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "operations done";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh I should comment that the variable $json['results_preview'] or $json["results_preview"] or $json['results_preview'][0] all return an array error or blank nothing

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to call `$json['result_preview'][0][0][0]` for you to get expected result.